# How to remove an array from a nested array, loop throug the rest of the arrays. And then loop throug 1 value of the nested arrays, all in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, pagerank

```
let linkMatrix = [
    [0,0,1,0],
    [1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,0,1],
    [0,1,0,0]
];


let newMatrix = [];

function linkToPage(){

    for(let j = 0; j < linkMatrix.length; j--){
        newMatrix = linkMatrix.splice(linkMatrix[j], 1);
        console.log(linkMatrix + " Here is linkMatrix");

        
            for(let i = 0; i < newMatrix.length; i++){
                newMatrix.splice(newMatrix[i]);
                console.log(newMatrix + " Here is newMatrix");
            }
        
    }
```

**What i'm trying to do is loop throug the first array but remove the fist array, because i don't need to loop throug that, then loop throug the rest of the arrays, but the only value i need is the value in the removed array's index, so to better understand: if we had an array that wore somthing like this arr = [[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] then remove [0,1] and because it is arr[0], i would like to loop throug the 0 index of the other arrays so i would get 1 and 1, then go back to the original array remove arr[1] and loop throug arr[0],arr[2] to the 1 index of the arrays so i would get [1,1] **

```
**Yeah, so the wanted result from my link matrix would be: 
    [0,0,1,0] = 2 
    [1,0,0,1] = 2
    [1,1,0,1] = 1
    [0,1,0,0] = 2
because there is 2 other arrys pointing to the first array, the same for the second and fourth, but there is only one array pointing to the third array
    **
```

Comment: [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns the deleted part of the array.

Comment: i want a singel array like [2,2,1,2] and i have added all results of given matrices

Comment: pointing to is because im trying to code a pagerank algo in js, so the first index of linkMatrix would be a website, where the 0 means not linking to, and the 1 means linking to, and then in the order in the array the 0's and 1's is added, to describe the connection between webpages

Comment: and because i want a number from each "webpage" index of linkMatrix, describing how meny other webpages is pointing to that specifik webpage, to calculate the pagerank of each webpage

Comment: Sure: webpages [0,1,1], [1,0,0] and [1,0,0] would be: [0,1,1] = 2, [1,0,0] = 1 and [1,0,0] = 1

Comment: [0,0,0],[1,0,0] and [1,1,0]: [0,0,0]= 2, [1,0,0] = 1 and [1,1,0] = 0

Comment: where do you get [1, 0, 0] in the last example from?

Comment: what do you mean about adding rows or columns?

Comment: yeah sorry about that it should be [1,1,0]

Comment: the last [1,0,0] it should be edidted now

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the values of the columns.

```js
const
    getColSum = matrix => matrix.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => (r[i] || 0) + v), []);

console.log(...getColSum([[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]));
console.log(...getColSum([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]));
```

A version without (nearly) array methods.

```js
function getColSum (matrix) {
    const result = Array(matrix[0].length).fill(0);

    for (const row of matrix) {
        for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) result[i] += row[i];
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(...getColSum([[0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]));
console.log(...getColSum([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]));
```

Comment: Do you know how to do that in vanilla js? (without build in functions like reduce or map), but this deffenently helps, so thanks alot :)

Comment: it take the first row of the matrix and from this the length. if you have quadratic matrices, you could take `matrix.length` instead. btw, for naming variables take only small letters, or for constants all uppercase and for instanciabel start with an upper case ltter and the rest small or as necessary.